# My ubuntu 16.04 failed load kernel when boot and stuck in tty

Tags: 16.04, boot, networking, kernel, updates

Ubuntu 16.04 I failed to load the kernel at boot and I was directed to the tty1 terminal, I was looking for it on google, how to fix it and find it

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install
init 6
```

but when I tried apt-get update it failed there was no internet connection even though the wifi connection was connected and I tried pinging 8.8.8.8 can but why when I apt-get update there was no connection.

please help me anyone :(

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your `ping 8.8.8.8` would confirm your network is working (if you get replies), but does not confirm DNS (domain name service) is working.  If you can't ping 'dns.google.com' but can ping it's ip address (8.8.8.8) then you have a DNS issue; what converts human names to internet addresses (the numbers).  Adding a nameserver (eg. `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the end of your `/etc/resolv.conf` will temporarily add google's to your list (this is temporary & won't survive network or machine restart).  I don't completely follow your question, but that may help get you a little..